# Remove application from autostart that isn't present in msconfig.exe / services.msc

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I have an **Asus PCE-AC68** wireless card and when I installed drivers for it, an additional app was installed (it's called Asus Control Center).

This app doesn't do anything, it's just a wrapper around Windows' wireless connectivity options.

This app loads each time I turn on my PC and I want to prevent it from doing so.

This app is not related to the drivers themselves, it can be shut down manually by the user (what I do currently).

I checked `msconfig.exe` and `services.msc` and I can't see anything related to this application.

What else can I do to prevent it from loading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check all different autostart options with Sysinternals [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and shows you the entries in the order Windows processes them. These programs include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys.

Answer (score 6):

There is a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler that launches "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\PCE-AC68 WLAN Card Utilities\WlanMgr.exe"  at user login.

You can disable it

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this page because I have an Asus USB-N13 wifi dongle bundled with software that presented the same problem on Windows 7. The software is called "Asus USB-N13 WLAN Control Center". The hardware may be a different model, but because it's the same brand, I assume that the software is the same albeit branded under a slightly different name. I don't know the specific details & features of your Asus PCE-AC68 wireless, but my dongle is capable of serving as a wireless access point in addition to being an Ethernet client. Though I agree that the Control Center software is redundant to the native Windows wireless software, it's necessary in "AP" (access point) mode. If your hardware does not have AP mode, then I suggest trying to uninstall the Control Center altogether, but leave the drivers installed & see if you can use it with the Windows wireless software.

In my case, I need AP mode so I need the software, but I don't want the Control Center to auto start since it's useless until I plug in the dongle. When I installed on XP there is a msconfig item called "Asus USB-N13 WLAN Control Center". I disabled it there, but on Windows 7 there is no such startup item. I tried Autoruns as suggested earlier, but could not find anything there.

I was able to find the item in services.msc. The service is called "Realtek11nCU". Here's the path: C:\Program Files\ASUS\USB-N13 WLAN Card Utilities\RtlService.exe

I opened its Properties from services.msc & changed its Start type from Automatic to Manual then rebooted...the System Tray icon was GONE!...at least until I run the Control Center manually from the Start Menu shortcut.

Comment: On Windows 10, this is called "AsusSE" in the services page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: ASUS WLAN Control Center would autostart, but did not appear in any of the usual startup locations.  I even perused services.msc and found nothing.  It's actually a bit worse: occasionally I would find multiple copies running -- sometimes *six at once* -- consuming 3~5% cpu each.

Anyway, it annoyed me again today, and looking up how to kill it led me to this QA.  Following the advice herein, I once again looked through services.msc, but was not able to find "Realtek11nCU" as mentioned above.  I did, however, find a promising entry for "AsusSE".  Setting that one to manual and stopping the service finally fixed it!

---

**Summary:**

**The services.msc entry may be titled either "Realtek11nCU" or "AsusSE" depending on the product version.  Setting its startup type to manual and stopping the service will resolve the issue.**